# Error getting Home Graph: sync error: 403: Please make sure you have resourcemanager.projects.get permission in Google Smart Home Action Test Suite

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I have completed all the procedures in the development process of the Google Smart Home action including Invocation, Actions, and Account linking.

However when I try to test the same, If I go to test suit and log in with my developer mail id and paste my action's project id, It throws an error:

> Error getting Home Graph: sync error: 403: Please make sure you have resourcemanager.projects.get permission on project 'project-id'

Comment: I was also getting this message. In my case, it took a while to notice that I wasn't logged in with my Google account.

Answer (score 6):

My bad, it was a more sort of invisible typo error.
I am not sure why, but when we copy the project ID from google action's console there is a space prefixed with the project id. Which causes this issue.

Make sure to remove extra whitespaces on both sides of the project ID and try again in the test suit.